# Avoiding awk injection

Tags: awk, pandoc

I have a script which reads an VCS log, converts that to latex, and then uses `awk` to replace keyword `@COMMITS@` in a template with the text:

```
untagged=$(get-commit-messages "$server" "$rev")
IFS=$'\n' untagged=( $untagged )  # Tokenize based on newlines
for commit in "${untagged[@]}"; do
  tex+="\\\nui{"                  # Wrap each commit in a custom command
  tex+=$(echo "$commit" | pandoc -t latex --wrap=none)
  tex+="}
"
done

awk -v r="$tex" '{gsub(/@COMMITS@/,r)}1' template
```

Since commit messages are really just text, I use `pandoc -t latex` to ensure everything is escaped properly for the latex parser.

My problem is that the `awk` parser un-escapes these.   If I find a `_` in a commit message, `pandoc` will replace that with `\_`, but then `awk` will convert it back and give a warning:

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\_' treated as plain `_'
```

That will cause the latex parser to fail.

Is there a way for me to prevent `awk` from un-escaping stuff?  If not I'll look for a non-`awk` solution for text-replacement.

Comment: If `r` can contain a backreference like `&` then `gsub(/@COMMITS@/,r)` will fail. If I were you I'd use literal string operations with `index()` and `substr()` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67852969/1745001 for more information on that if you're interested and then ask a new question if you can't figure out how to make it work for you.

Comment: In `IFS=$'\n' untagged=( $untagged )`, you're using the split+glob operator to split `$untagged` but forgot to disable the glob part (also note that it strips empty lines). In `bash`, see also `readarray -t untagged <<< "$untagged"` to get one array element per line.

Comment: See also [external variable in awk](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/56141) (or [Use a shell variable in awk](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/56190)) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: I don't think your `pandoc` line does what you want. See for instance `echo '%foo' | pandoc -t latex --wrap=none`

Comment: By the way - you won't need as many escapes inside your shell strings if you use the correct quotes. Always use single quotes unless you NEED double quotes and then use double unless you NEED none. If you follow that rule then `tex+="\\\nui{"` becomes `tex+='\\nui{'`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more info.

Comment: Another note on `pandoc`: Is this OK? https://termbin.com/3w8u => out https://termbin.com/3fc8 (limited test, but shows some)

Comment: Not sure if it is needed, or it helps you, but https://www.mail-archive.com/templates@template-toolkit.org/msg07971.html is a routine used in Template-Toolkit (http://template-toolkit.org) - or perhaps they have updated it, but none the less.

Comment: @ibuprofen Good summary on things that `pandoc` does.  Those outputs actually look really good (better than I expected).  Fortunately, I control the first few characters are integers so I don't expect a `%` in the first character sent to pandoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking awk to interpret escape sequences when setting the variable by using `-v` so don't do that - use `ENVIRON[]` or `ARGV[]` instead to set the awk variable to a literal string:

```
$ shellvar='foo\tbar'

$ awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'BEGIN{print awkvar}'
foo     bar

$ shellvar="$shellvar" awk 'BEGIN{awkvar=ENVIRON["shellvar"]; print awkvar}'
foo\tbar

$ awk 'BEGIN{awkvar=ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[1]; print awkvar}' "$shellvar"
foo\tbar
```

See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for more information.